# Possible mistakes in an russian online course. Could you proof-read it please?

Tags: грамматика

right not I try to make the Russian course from RT and I guess they have some mistakes in there tasks and I ask you kindly if you could take a look at it.

**Task 4 - Number 1** 
*http://learnrussian.rt.com/lessons/genitive-case-plural-quantity/*

```
У вас есть визы? У нас нет виз.
```

I think "ы" is wrong because it is about more than one visa right?

**Task 3 - Number 8** 
*http://learnrussian.rt.com/lessons/genitive-case-plural-quantity/*

```
Мы купили 5 машин.
```

In my understanding they forgot to add the "ы" because the case is accusativ plural.

**Task 3 - Number 8** 
*/lessons/nouns-adjectives-possessive-pronouns-plural/*

```
В России много красивых девушек.
```

If I look into the dictionary the plural prepositional case of "girl" is девуш**ках** so why did they девуш**ек**?

I appreciate your answers! Thanking you in advance!

Comment: I should disillusion you, all the sentences you quoted are absolutely correct.

Comment: I would only suggest changing to a capital letter in the first example: "У вас есть визы? _У_ нас нет виз." Question mark splits it into 2 sentences.

Comment: @user244413 Done.

Comment: Welcome to Russian SE. I have to warn you that questions related to "proof-reading" homeworks are off-topic hear. Though you can choose one of the difficulties that bothers you and create related question. But listing separate items just on the grounds it's your homework is off-topic.

Answer (score 3):

**Task 4 - Number 1**

```
У вас есть визы? у нас нет виз.
```

Correct. It is about more than one visa, so plural is used.

**Task 3 - Number 8**

```
Мы купили 5 машин.
```

Correct. Russian plurals are bit more complicated, than in english. Nouns have two plural forms, correct form depends on amount of items (two last digits in number):

```
Last digits                     form
01, 21, 31, ... 91              машина
02 - 04, 22 - 24, 32 - 34, ...  машины
05 - 20, 25 - 29, 35 - 39, ...  машин
```

Why? It's very long story...

**Task 3 - Number 8**

```
В России много красивых девушек.
```

It is genitive case, not prepositional.

Comment: 4 машины, but not «*5 машины» as you wrote. You wrote: "02 - 05, 22 - 24, 32 - 34, ...  машины".

Answer (score 1):

All is correct.

4-1. "Визы" is nominative plural here (coincides with both accusative plural and genitive singular); "Виз" is genitive plural.

3-8. This is due to dual vs plural historical difference. "Две (три, четыре) машины" but "пять (шесть, семь, ..., двадцать) машин".

3-8. This is genitive not a prepositional.

Comment: I would say that in 4-1 it's nominative plural, not accusative. Есть (кто? что?)

Comment: @MigMit Yes, my fault.